# Запомнить действие пользователя на странице - клик по ссылке, при следующем посещении этой страницы переадресовать на ранее выбранную

Tags: wordpress, cookie, popup

Помогите пожалуйста совсем не программисту.
Есть ли возможность сделать на странице_1 сайта(во всплывающем окне которое по сути страница_3), запомнить выбранную посетителем ссылку на страницу_2  и при следующем его входе на страницу_1 открыть страницу_2.
А если на странице_2 открыть всплывающее окно-страница_3 и выбрать другую ссылку, то при следующем посещении страницы_1 перенаправить по новой выбранной ссылке.